# What do I need to run C# application built with Xamarin Studio...?

Tags: c#, monodevelop, xamarin-studio

I am just starting to build apps using C#, I am using Xamarin Studio for it. And I have a few questions about it:

1. Provided that my Xamarin Studio version is 5.9, what are the requirements of the apps I make using it. (like .NET version ??...) (I will be developing for Windows)
2. What is the difference between MonoDevelop and Xamarin Studio, If I try to download MonoDevelop from its own website, it downloads Xamarin Studio!?

If you can answer my question, I'll be really thankful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Monodevelop, Xamarin-studio using same codebase, the different is xamarin plugin to develop mobile app (iOS, Android, OSX).
If you want develop app for Windows you should consider using [Visual Studio Community Edition](https://www.visualstudio.com/) (Check license term before use it) or [Sharpdevelop](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SD/Default.aspx) (Free)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I choose MonoDevelop instead of Visual Studio. And you didn't answer the whole question, what I need to run apps built with Xamarin Studio 5.9?

Comment: I just checked SharpDevelop. Thanks a million for that!